# How can a call a java method from javascript?

Tags: java, android, webview, rewardedvideoad

I am trying to integrate admob rewarded video ads into my web view app. How can I go about this using javascript?

I've already loaded the videos but am confused on how to display it upon button click with javascript.

```
private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
    mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
            new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}

@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewarded! currency: " + reward.getType() + "  amount: " +
            reward.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Reward the user.
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoCompleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public class MyJavaScriptInterface {

    @JavascriptInterface // this annotation is important
    public void startRewardVideoAndroidFunction(String paramFromJS) {
        if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                mRewardedVideoAd.show();
        }
    }
}
```

When a button is clicked on the page, I need to run a javascript function that calls the java method.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the above problem
Import all the required packages.

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Load the next rewarded video ad.
    loadAd();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoCompleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void loadAd() {
    if (!mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    }
}

public void displayLoadedAd(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                mRewardedVideoAd.show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ad not Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
public class MyJavaScriptInterface {



     @JavascriptInterface
    public void startRewardVideoAndroidFunction() {
        // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         displayLoadedAd();
    }
}
```